# How to run docker image as singleton

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker.

I have an image that I want to run, but I want docker to see if that image is already running from another terminal...if it is running I don't want it to load another one...

is this something that can be done with docker?

if it helps, I'm running the docker with a privileged mode.

I've tried to search for singleton docker or something like that, but no luck.

updates-
1.working from ubuntu. 
My scenario- from terminal X I run `docker run Image_a`
from terminal Y I run `docker run Image_a`
when trying to run from terminal Y, I want docker to check if there is already a docker running with Image_a, and the answer is true - I want docker not to run in terminal Y

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following docker command to get all containers that running from specific image:

```
docker ps  --filter ancestor="imagename:tag"
```

Example:

```
docker ps  --filter ancestor="drone/drone:0.5"
```

Example Output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3fb00087d4c1        drone/drone:0.5     "/drone agent"      6 days ago          Up 26 minutes       8000/tcp            drone_drone-agent_1
```

This approach uses docker api and docker daemon, so it doesnt matter if the run command executed in background or other terminal.

Aother approach:

If you have a single container form a single image:

Try naming your containers, You cant have 2 containers with the same name:

```
docker run --name uniquecontainer Image_a
```

Next time you run the above command you will get an error. Btw consider using `-d` so you dont have to switch terminals.

```
docker run -d --name uniquecontainer Image_a
```

Comment: I need something that will run when I use the docker command, and I cannot run docker ps from inside docker...
if I do what you said I have to first check and then run docker...which is what I don't want to do....

Comment: I still dont understand your requirements, Please edit your question to describe it better. Do you want to know if a container from an image is running, from inside of another container?

Comment: I've add more info, tell me if it is still not clear. thanks!

Comment: thanks! it works. will mark as correct in a minute. do you know how to set it with docker-compose?

Comment: Try : `container_name: my-web-container`, in version 3