# docker compose- how to set name property

Tags: docker, docker-compose

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548784/how-to-run-docker-image-as-singleton#42549160) question I wanted to know if there is an option to add the name tag to the compose.yml file.

From what I've seen online, it says to use container_name property.

but that is not good in my case, since I want to make sure that the image is only running once, and altho the container_name is unique, at each run the docker-compose will append to it the run number, so only if I try to run the image twice at the same time one run will fail.

I need to find a way to set a parameter in the yml file, that will help me to make sure that the image is running only once.
any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `container_name` doesn't work for you, the output of the `docker-compose up` may suggest otherwise, but it creates a container with that name:

```
$ cat docker-compose.name.yml
version: '2'

services:
  test:
    image: busybox:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    container_name: unique_name

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.name.yml up -d
Recreating test_test_1

$ docker ps -a | grep test_test_1

$ docker ps -a | grep unique
80b44bc94912        busybox:latest      "tail -f /dev/null"      About a minute ago   Up 59 seconds   

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.name.yml scale test=3
Creating and starting unique_name ... error
Creating and starting unique_name ...

ERROR: for unique_name  Cannot create container for service test: Conflict. The container name "/unique_name" is already in use by container 80b44bc94912b755cf2430b132fa6112f960e2752f69a357c27375bbc905ff76. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```